# How to search for empty cells in a specific column in a CSV file for all rows?

Tags: c#, csv

Goal: Search through a specific single column in a CSV for empty rows only in that column and replace with string "No Box".

Attempts: So far I have tried to use CsvHelper and CsvTools(CsvReader) via Nuget C#. I am not very experienced with C# so not sure how to accomplish my task. Searching did not turn up any examples or references that helped me understand what I need to implement. There are a lot of similar questions, but none of them searched a specific column. I am hoping someone can provide me with advice on how to get my for loop to work and get the number of rows for my checking.

Image sample of my CSV file.
[Sample of CSV data column Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy9Vl.jpg)

```
private static void SiteBlanks()
{           
    try
    {
        MutableDataTable dt = DataAccess.DataTable.New.ReadCsv(@"C:\temp.csv");

        for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++) // Cannot be applied to data types, so this errors.
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.GetRow(i)["Site"])) // Check if cells in column 1 are empty
            {
                dt.Columns[1].Values[i] = "No Box"; // Update empty values with No Box

            }
        }
        dt.SaveCSV(@"C:\temp.csv"); // Save file after changes.
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Set Error message
        Error("ERROR: SiteBlanks()", ex);
    }
}
```

Note: This is my first question ever asked so be gentle and tell me what I may have did wrong posting wise.

Comment: you try update such as: "if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.GetRow(i)["Site"]))".

Comment: I actually did try something similar to that in my old method based on an example I saw. I did not have the increment though. Testing with that form now.

Comment: You shouldn't save a copy of c:\temp.csv file for every row you check.

Comment: That removed the error I was getting for the string check. Any idea on how to accurately check for the row count so that it cycles through each cell of a specific column?

Comment: You are correct, I moved that line outside of the for loop. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Create a row variable `var row = dt.GetRow(i)` and then do your check and updates on that variable. after your condition check

Comment: What about my for loop check? I took your advice, but I still have the error my for loop gives for trying to get the number of rows to check when compiling. Error: Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'

Comment: Which number of rows do you need. Total rows in file or total updated. Because `dt.Rows.Count` represents the total rows in file while you can add a counter inside condition to count how many were updated

Comment: I just need the total in the column Site. In my example it has 15 rows. So that it knows where to stop. Total in the file.

Comment: `dt.Rows.Count` will give you the number of rows

Comment: That is the line I used in my for loop because I thought the same. However, when I compile it gives me the error:  Operator '<=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'.

Comment: Ok I checked the source code for `MutableDataTable` and it has a `NumRows` property that returns total number of rows. Check my answer

Comment: Nikosi, in your code on line 5 you are missing the () at the end of dt.Rows.Count. Your code changes worked for me and with the help of everyone else I think my problem is solved. I thank you all so much.

Comment: Oh, that change works too! I am going with the use of NumRows.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct. Thanks everyone. All of your insights help drive the solution. Thanks for making this experience welcoming and educational.

Comment: @Sky Thanks, glad to help and welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your current code you can try the following

```
private static void SiteBlanks() {
    try {
        string filePath = @"C:\temp.csv";
        MutableDataTable dt = DataTable.New.ReadCsv(filePath);
        string columnName = "Site";         
        var numberOfRows = dt.NumRows ;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRows; i++) {
            var row = dt.GetRow(i);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[columnName])) {
                row[columnName] = "No Box";
            }
        }
        dt.SaveCSV(filePath);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Set Error message
        Error("ERROR: SiteBlanks()", ex);
    }
}
```